Incorrect word count using Cheerio
I am trying to calculate the word count of an HTML page using Cheerio in the following Gulp task:
gulp.task("html", () => {
    try {
        return gulp.src(folder.src + "html/**/*.html")
            .pipe(preprocess())
            .pipe(htmlmin({
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                removeComments: true,
                minifyCSS: true,
                minifyJS: true
            }))
            .pipe(cheerio(function ($, file) {
                try {
                    const text = $("body").children(":not(header, footer, script)").text();

                    const words = text.split(/\s+/).filter(word => word.length > 0)
                    const wordCount = words.length;

                    const filename = file.relative;

                    if (filename == "clients.html") {
                        console.log(words);

                    }

                    console.log(wordCount, filename);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                }
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(folder.build));
    } catch (error) {
        console.warn("Error parsing HTML: ", error);
    }
});


While this works, I am encountering an issue where words are not being split properly. For example, I get results like:
[
  'Our',           'Valued',            'ClientsAt',
  'Zubizi',        'Web',               'Solutions,'
]

The issue seems to be with the word "clientsAt", which should be split into two separate words ("Clients" and "At"), but instead, they are combined.
Here’s the HTML snippet I’m working with:

            <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold mb-3">Our Valued Clients</h1>
            <p class="text-lg mb-5">
                At Zubizi Web Solutions,
                ...

And since i am using gulp minify the the output is as follows:
<h1>Our Valued Clients</h1><p>At Zubizi Web Solutions,</p></h1>

As you can see, the text "ClientsAt" is not properly split. How can I fix this issue? I even tried it jquery, and it still results the same.
FYI: the client.html is: https://zubizi.com/clients.html
Note: I am attempting to perform keyword analysis during the compilation process.

Is gulp actually relevant to the problem/question? I'd remove it if not, because it's distracting and makes the code harder to reproduce locally. If the problem is strictly Cheerio, then I would hardcode in a string and run it through cheerio specifically. This makes it easier to answer and more useful for future visitors with the same problem as you (it's unlikely they'll also be using both gulp and cheerio).

Gulp is related because it's minifying. So a [mcve] would be hardcoded input HTML <h1>Our Valued Clients</h1><p>At Zubizi Web Solutions,</p></h1>, which Cheerio turns into Our Valued ClientsAt Zubizi Web Solutions, after calling .text(). A simple log before your split call would reveal this.

@ggorlen how do i fix this, i even tried with jquery and it returns the same

The posted answer works for me if I run Cheerio on the input you've edited in, <h1>Our Valued Clients</h1><p>At Zubizi Web Solutions,</p></h1>, so you'll need to provide reproduction details and a minimal example, as requested, if that answer doesn't work for you for some reason.

(Caveat: I have neither run your code nor tested the below fully)
It seems likely that you are experiencing the same behavior reported in this question:  How to get the text of multiple elements split by delimiter using jQuery?
If that assessment is accurate, code like the below, which is adapted from that question's accepted answer, may be of use
const text = $("body")
  .children(":not(header, footer, script)")
  .map(function () {
    return $(this).text();
  })
  .get()
  .join(" ");

Basically, the idea is to intersperse a space between text from different elements; under your current approach, that content is being joined without a delimiter by the call to .text().

I tried that, but still same response. FYI the page i am to get the text is: https://zubizi.com/clients.html

Apologies. In continuing to experiment, I see that my analysis was incorrect and oversimplified the problem. I haven't come up with a working solution, but I will continue to experiment and will post here if I find something better.

Please don't accept this as an answer, even if it works, because I'm sure that someone more proficient in JavaScript and jQuery could provide a better solution, but in limited experimentation, this seems to be working for me: $("body").children(":not(header, footer, script)").contents().find('*').map(function(){return $(this).text()}).get().join(' ')
